# Warning - The value of the field EggBox.boxSize is not used

Tags: java, class

I am working on Instantiable classes. I have wrote my code on two separate files but I see the following warning on my EggBox file - The value of the field EggBox.boxSize is not used. However the program runs as expected and I still get the input methods for the user.

If I delete the variable int boxSize then I end up with this warning - Multiple markers at this line- Line breakpoint:EggBox [line: 12] - setboxSize(int)- boxSize cannot be resolved or is not a field

This is an exercise of filling in the blanks that I am trying to complete. It is the last piece of code

The eggBoxApp has no error or warnings

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class EggBoxApp{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //variables
        int eggs;
        int boxSize;
        int numBoxes;
        int leftOverEggs;
        //objects
        EggBox egg;
        egg=new EggBox();
        //inputs
        eggs=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a number of eggs"));
        boxSize=6;
        //set
        egg.setEggs(eggs);
        egg.setboxSize(boxSize);
        //compute
        egg.computeBoxes();
        egg.computeLeftOver();
        //get
        eggs=egg.getBoxes();
        eggs=egg.getLeftOver();
        //output
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of boxes needed "+numBoxes);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Number of eggs left over "+leftOverEggs);
    }
}

public class EggBox{
    //vars
    private int eggs;
    private int boxSize;
    private int numBoxes;
    private int leftOverEggs;
    //set
    public void setEggs(int eggs){
        this.eggs=eggs;
    }
    public void setboxSize(int boxSize){
        this.boxSize=boxSize;
    }
    //compute
    public void computeBoxes(){
        numBoxes=eggs/6;
    }
    public void computeLeftOver(){
        leftOverEggs=eggs%6;
    }
    //get
    public int getBoxes(){
        return numBoxes;
    }
    public int getLeftOver(){
        return leftOverEggs;
    }
}

public class EggBox{
    //vars
    **** int eggs;
    **** **** boxSize;
    **** **** numBoxes;
    **** **** leftOverEggs;
    //set
    public **** setEggs(int eggs){
        this.eggs=eggs;
    }
    public **** setBoxSize(int ****){
        this.****=****;
    }
    //compute
    public void computeBoxes(){
        numBoxes=eggs/6;
    }
    public void computeLeftover(){
        leftOverEggs=****;
    }
    //get
    public **** getBoxes(){
        return boxes;
    }
    public **** getLeftover(){
        return leftover;
    }
}
```

I understand it is a warning but I am not sure how to proceed or fix it. Any help explaining this would be great. Thanks

Comment: A method such as `setBoxSize()` (note the correct capitalisation of the letter B) would normally have a corresponding method `getBoxSize()`. If you define such a method and have it return `boxSize`, the warning should go away.

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly encourage you to start declaring local variables at the point of first use, rather than declaring them all before assigning anything to any of them. It makes code much easier to read, in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the value of the attribute `boxSize`, but after setting it you never use it.

The warning is based on the fact that if you set a variable, you probably intend to use it, right ?

If you just want to make the warning disappear, you could add some getter (like `getBoxSize()`) that would return the value of your attribute, and call it.